# Story identification: Man working from home is isolated, becomes paranoid about invasion outside, blind himself- twist is that he is right

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

He realises he hasn't communicated with anyone for a couple of days and soon descends into a paranoid state. I think he worked in IT? During story can't tell if he is crazy or not as he is so paranoid and unreliable.

He calls a female friend which leads to his downfall as the outside invaders realise he is still himself.

He then blinds himself as the "police" etc come to his door.

The end is him in a psych ward where the nurses and doctors try and convince him he's crazy. Last paragraph is the twist where the doctor is actually held hostage by some invader thing (tendrils?!) and the doctor is hoping he holds out and doesn't give in.

DRIVING ME CRAZY!!! Please let me know if you recognise.

Comment: I remember this story. I read it on CreepyPasta- funnily enough it's the only story I've read from that site. I don't remember what it's called though. Wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like the CreepyPasta [Psychosis](http://www.creepypasta.com/psychosis/):

> The doctor wanted to smile. He wanted to whisper words of encouragement to the delusional man. He wanted to scream, but the nerve filaments wrapped around his head and into his eyes made him do otherwise. His body walked into the cell like a puppet, and told the patient, once more, that he was wrong, and that there was nobody trying to deceive him.